# ad hoc distribution in iPhone app Not working

Tags: ios, ipad

I am installing on ipad app using adhoc distribution. When i build that using simulator and load that file .app in ipad it does not install says not signed. But when i debug using device again not installing

Comment: Do you have a paid app developer account?

Comment: Did you install the provisioning profile to the device?

Comment: yes i have paid developer program

Comment: how may i install the provsioning profile to device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't sign your app properly. following link helps you for creating provision profile properly.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlRI30F6-Ek&feature=related

and for installing app over device.

The application and a provisioning profile. You need to install both files into iTunes to be able run the application on your device.
After opening the archive:

Drag the provisioning profile (the file with the .mobileprovision extension) to the iTunes Library group.

Drag the application (the file with the .app extension) to the iTunes Library group.
The application appears in the Applications list.

Sync your device.

If the version of iPhone OS on your device is earlier than the test application can run on, you need to update your device with the current release of iPhone OS.